# Cannot create new folder under Storage Root - Magento Media Gallery

Tags: magento2, media-images

I get the attached error while creating a new folder under Storage Root.  How can I fix this?? Is it not possible to create another folder under root[image]

**Edit**
There were folders under StorageRoot that disappeared after upgrade from Magento 2.4.4 to 2.4.5.  The folders are visible in pub/media, but are not visible in admin panel media gallery.

Comment: No, you cannot create new folder under Storage Root. Its magento default feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Magento 2.4.3-p1, for security purposes Magento only allows the media gallery access to the following two directories under `/pub/media`:

- `catalog/category`
- `wysiwyg`

In versions 2.4.3-p1 and higher, you must modify media library folder permissions in a 'config.xml' file.

The configuration path `system/media_storage_configuration/allowed_resources/media_gallery_image_folders` in `config.xml` defines the "Media Gallery Allowed" folders.

To extend "Media Gallery Allowed" folders using the `config.xml` file, follow the following steps:

1. Create a `config.xml` file.

If your module does not have one, create a `config.xml` file under the `etc` directory.

2. Add a new "Media Gallery Allowed" folder:

```
<system>
   <media_storage_configuration>
      <allowed_resources>
         <media_gallery_image_folders>
            <!-- new "Media Gallery Allowed" folders -->
            <my_image_folder>custom_folder_name</my_image_folder>
            <my_catalog_image_folder>catalog/custom_folder_name</my_catalog_image_folder>
         </media_gallery_image_folders>
      </allowed_resources>
   </media_storage_configuration>
</system>
```

where `custom_folder_name` and `catalog/custom_folder_name` are folder paths under `/pub/media`.

Source: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/backend/modify-image-library-permissions/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Whitelisted the folders this way and it worked.  For those looking for answer, whitelisting folders will display if the folder already exists, creates a new one if it doesn't exist

Comment: @Siri If my answer helps you resolve your issue or in case you already resolve your issue but no answer was given, you can see my answer is the only answer in this topic, if it is correct, please mark it as **accepted**. That will helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: okay, though I had already fixed this, accepting the answer that might help others

Answer (score 0):

Do my way for declaring is correct . Please find the code below.

```
<system>
    <media_storage_configuration>
        <allowed_resources>
            <media_gallery_image_folders>
                <downloadable>downloadable</downloadable>
            </media_gallery_image_folders>
        </allowed_resources>
    </media_storage_configuration>
</system>
```

**

I am facing below error while running setup:upgrade or setup:di:compile

**" is invalid:
Element 'system': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( default, stores, websites ).
Line: 3

Verify the XML and try again.****

Please let me know, If I did some mistake in this code.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Need to add this code under the <default></default> handle. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues when I try to add an image to a cms page.
I'm just seeing the 'storage root' directory navigation with the 'loading' icon [Image](https://prnt.sc/To7QEeDDfrqm). Just hangs.
This after upgrading to Magento 2.4.3-p3
Where does the config.xml go after adding the 'allowed_resources'?
Before the upgrade I could see several folders within the wysiwyg folder.
Help appreciated.
Andy

Comment: you can add it in app/code/<yourvendor>/catalog/etc/config.xml

Comment: What would the '<yourvendor>' be?
Would it be module-cms as the vendor ?

Comment: under app/code...you should have something which is your vendor...please read about creating your own module

Comment: But I'm not even seeing the wysiwyg folder. The folder list doesn't load.