# wysiwyg editor does not show all folder after upgrading to Magento 2.4.6

Tags: catalog, permissions, wysiwyg, media-images, editor

I just upgraded to Magento 2.4.6 from 2.4.0. The issue i am facing is the editor is not showing images folder in storage_root. It is just showing me two folder catalog/category and Wyswig folder. I am not sure what is the issue. The folders are present in pub/media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Magento 2.4.3-p1, by default, Magento only allows access to the two following directories under `pub/media` for security purposes:

- `catalog/category`
- `wysiwyg`

In versions 2.4.3-p1 and higher, you must modify media library folder permissions in a 'config.xml' file.

The configuration path `system/media_storage_configuration/allowed_resources/media_gallery_image_folders` in `config.xml` defines the "Media Gallery Allowed" folders.

To extend "Media Gallery Allowed" folders using the `config.xml` file, follow the following steps:

1. Create a `config.xml` file.

If your module does not have one, create a `config.xml` file under the `etc` directory.

2. Add a new "Media Gallery Allowed" folder:

```
<system>
   <media_storage_configuration>
      <allowed_resources>
         <media_gallery_image_folders>
            <!-- new "Media Gallery Allowed" folders -->
            <my_image_folder>custom_folder_name</my_image_folder>
            <my_catalog_image_folder>catalog/custom_folder_name</my_catalog_image_folder>
         </media_gallery_image_folders>
      </allowed_resources>
   </media_storage_configuration>
</system>
```

where `custom_folder_name` and `catalog/custom_folder_name` are folder paths under `/pub/media`.

Source: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/backend/modify-image-library-permissions/

P/S: This is a duplicate post related to the issue of  [Cannot create new folder under Storage Root - Magento Media Gallery](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/362389/cannot-create-new-folder-under-storage-root-magento-media-gallery)

Comment: Yes. I did the same and it is now displaying. Just to confirm i allowed all the the folder inside pub/media to display . Is that fine?

Comment: No, it is not not acceptable. By allowing access to all folders inside `pub/media`, you are going against Magento's efforts to ensure the safety of the site and prevent attacks.